# Change the body background related to the menu selection

Tags: menu, background, transition

I am new in learning CSS3.
I have stuck on the same problem for couple days.
So I am using this tutorial for practice and else.
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3Accordion/

And I get familiar with how it works. Now I want to try to combined them with background slider. In short, I want the body background to change (with transition effect, fade in fade out for example), everytime I click on the menu.

For example: About us -> background change to my photo, How we work -> picture of books or something.

I tried to use div to replace the body background to show up independently on top of each other but I just can't get it to work properly.

Can anyone give me basic solution? Thank you!